# How Can I delete begins with <tag> and ends with </tag>

Tags: php

I want to delete `<h1>`xxx yyyy zzz `</h1>` with php. But, first, I want to control if string starts with `<h1>` and ends with `</h1>`

Is there a function for this purspose?

```
if(string begins with '<h1>' and ends with '</h1>'){

    replace `<h1>`xxx yyyy zzz `</h1>` to 'NULL or empty space'

}
```

Comment: I'm sorry.. this isn't completely clear. What do you mean by `control`?

Comment: `preg_replace()` will do the trick :) Regular expressions rules!

Comment: "Regular expressions rules!"? http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1447657

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about just using a regular expression?

```
$string = preg_replace( "/<h1>(.*?)<\\/h1>/", "", $string );
```

The `*?` is to make it non-greedy

Comment: Is that a typo? should be `<\\/h1>`

Comment: Oops. Thanks for catching that.

Comment: This will also remove `<h1>skjgkdjjfkkjdfjdf</h1> jdfjdfdfjdf<h1>jfjdfjfd</h1>`.

Comment: @amal-murali, Having the `*?` will prevent that issue

Comment: Regex is not a tool that can be used to correctly parse HTML. regex-infection wil​l devour your HT​ML parser,ich​or permeates all MY FACE MY FACE ᵒh god no NO NOO̼O​O NΘ stop the an​*̶͑̾̾​̅ͫ͏̙̤g͇̫͛͆̾ͫ̑͆l͖͉̗̩̳̟̍ͫͥͨe̠̅s ͎a̧͈͖r̽̾̈́͒͑e n​ot rè̑ͧ̌aͨl̘̝̙̃ͤ͂̾̆ ZA̡͊͠͝LGΌ ISͮ̂҉̯͈͕̹̘̱ TO͇̹̺ͅƝ̴ȳ̳ TH̘Ë͖́̉ ͠P̯͍̭O̚​N̐Y̡ H̸̡̪̯ͨ͊̽̅̾̎Ȩ̬̩̾͛ͪ̈́̀́͘ ̶̧̨̱̹̭̯ͧ̾ͬC̷̙̲̝͖ͭ̏ͥͮ͟Oͮ͏̮̪̝͍M̲̖͊̒ͪͩͬ̚̚͜Ȇ̴̟̟͙̞ͩ͌͝S̨̥̫͎̭ͯ̿̔̀ͅ See http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/325521

Comment: Why do people try to manipulate HTML with Regex?  It's insane.  Use a parser such as [Simple HTML DOM](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) if you are using PHP

Comment: For small tasks, regex is more lightweight and possibly easier to read.

Comment: @Amal this won't remove because the `*?` operator is non-greedy

Answer (score 2):

Regular expressions are not the right tool for this job. Use a DOM parser to parse HTML. Here's a solution using the built-in [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/domdocument) class.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$your_html_string = '<h1>xxx yyyy zzz </h1>';
$dom->loadHTML($your_html_string);

$h1_tags = $dom->getElementsByTagname('h1');

// array of elements that are to be removed
$remove = array();
foreach ($h1_tags as $tag) {
    $remove[] = $tag;
}

// remove them
foreach($h1_tags as $tag) {
    $tag->parentNode->removeChild($tag);
}

// remove the DOCTYPE/html/body tags that DOM adds by default
$html = preg_replace(
    '~<(?:!DOCTYPE|/?(?:html|head|body))[^>]*>\s*~i', '', $dom->saveHTML()
);

echo $html;
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/101477)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $string = '<h1>AbcXycKasOkasdMpal</h1>';
    $pattern = '/<h1>.*<\/h1>/i';
    $replacement = '';
    echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
?>
```

By using regular expressions and the PHP `preg_replace` function you can pinpoint and replace every string starting with `<h1>` and ending `</h1>` with a blank string.

If you don't want to replace, look into `preg_match`.

---

**Edit:** changed to fix what @SyntaxLAMP pointed out.

Comment: <\/h1> you mean.  Gotta escape